# GitHub clone to desktop uses TortoiseGit instead of GitHub Desktop

Tags: github, tortoisegit, git-clone

When i try to clone a repository to desktop the default app for cloning has suddenly became TortoiseGit instead of GitHub. Anyone with a fix?

[image: github-tortoise]

Answer (score 13):

The following fix is a permanent solution for this issue that also withstands TortoisGit-updates/repairs.

It adds GitHubDesktop's protocol-associations the way described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/default-programs.

Add to the registry *(You can save this content as `.reg` file and double-click it to auto-import these keys into registry)*:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GitHubDesktop]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GitHubDesktop\Capabilities]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GitHubDesktop\Capabilities\UrlAssociations]
"github-windows"="github-windows"
"x-github-client"="x-github-client"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
"GitHubDesktop"="Software\\GitHubDesktop\\Capabilities"
```

Or, for those who like to simply execute some command lines from an admin console/powershell:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\GitHubDesktop\Capabilities\UrlAssociations /v github-windows /t REG_SZ /d github-windows /f
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\GitHubDesktop\Capabilities\UrlAssociations /v x-github-client /t REG_SZ /d x-github-client /f
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications /v GitHubDesktop /t REG_SZ /d Software\GitHubDesktop\Capabilities /f
```

Reboot or on a windows-server sign-out and log-in.

The next time a project is cloned from github, a message-box popped-up asking to pick an app.

GitHubDesktop will now also be available in the Windows settings: *Choose default apps by protocol*. So it can be recovered with Windows settings, if TortoisGit (or another app) was chosen as default handler for GitHub-clone.

I also opened a new error at GitHubDesktop-development: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/8258

Comment: Good to know. I wish I could test this but I ended deleting tGit and use only GithubDesktop. Let us know if anyone else tried this.

Comment: @Nomik - I manually added these entries to the registry and it resolved my issue. I am now prompted to use either Tortoise or GitHub desktop.

Comment: thanks! still work !and I now know why github url (x-github-client) is handled by tortoiseGit instead of github desktop, because tortoiseGit add a registry setting to make itself to handle x-github-client (see HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseGit\Proc\Capabilities\UrlAssociations)

Answer (score 2):

change windows registry is not working.

I have met the same problem and the registry is all right,but github desktop wont come out.

As a software developer,I used url protocol once.I cannt understand why   Windows setting is not related to the ROOT registry . I would appreciate a comment.

[image]

[image]

here is how i solve the problem:

After uninstall tortoise and reinstall github. Chrome works fine.

When you install tortoise,be careful with this setting:
[image]

but even if you unchecked this,x-github-client is registed to tortoisegit client again.

You can check it in your windows setting of default apps - choose default apps by protocal.

So i think this is a bug for tortisegit.
I use tortoisegit 2.7.0 and win10 1809.
If you really want github desktop to popup , you should not install tortoisegit

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in 2.6.0 which made TortoiseGit the default if the github handler was enabled on installation.

To fix this, go to the default programs settings in Windows, open the file-type associations dialog and set `github-windows` and `x-github-client` back to the official github client. Maybe you have to update to TortoiseGit 2.7.0 first.

cf. https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-file-associations-windows

---

You could try whether the hard way works: (Store this as a `.reg` file and import it, you need to madjust the paths)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\github-windows]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\github-windows]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="URL:github-windows"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\github-windows\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\GitHubDesktop\\app-1.4.2\\GitHubDesktop.exe\" --protocol-launcher \"%1\""

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\x-github-client]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\x-github-client]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="URL:x-github-client"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\x-github-client\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\GitHubDesktop\\app-1.4.2\\GitHubDesktop.exe\" --protocol-launcher \"%1\""
```

Comment: This is really helpful but the problem is that when i try to change the x-github-client default app for example, i got only the TortoiseGit as an option and the default "Look for an App in the Store".

Comment: I was unable to make it work. It is really weird that this is happening only on Chrome, since Firefox asks for the default program.

Comment: Maybe Chrome stores its own handlers and this has to be configured there...

Comment: Hard way doesn't work for me. Somehow still referring to Tortoise. After reboot

Answer (score 0):

This is based on tobias.loew answer:

If you don't have this line at the start:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

Script won't compile

Create github.reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GitHubDesktop]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GitHubDesktop\Capabilities]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\GitHubDesktop\Capabilities\UrlAssociations]
"github-windows"="github-windows"
"x-github-client"="x-github-client"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
"GitHubDesktop"="Software\\GitHubDesktop\\Capabilities"
```

Put this in a file called github.reg and then double click it.